# Problema al sacar datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, array, pdo

Tengo Menu(comida) dentro de esos menus tengo submenus(primeros,segundo,etc) y dentro de submenus tengo platos.

Los submenus me los genera perfecto y en cuanto los platos siempre me los rellena con los ultimos platos del ultimo id submenu con lo cual siempre me saca los mismo platos en en todos los submenus aunq sean distintos.

Crud de menu:

```
    /*SUBMENUS DE UN MENU*/
public function justSubMenu($arrayMenu,$id_menu){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($arrayMenu as $key => $value) {
        if($value['id'] == $id_menu) {
            array_push($result, $value['nombre']);

        }
    }
    return array_unique($result);;
}
/*PLATOS DE UN SUBMENU*/
public function platosSubMenu($arrayMenu,$id_submenu){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($arrayMenu as $key => $value) {
        if ($value[3] == $id_submenu) {
            array_push($result, $value[0]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Y como muestro los datos,

```
<?php
$infoMenu = $crudMenu->platosMenu($_GET['id_menu']);

$submenus = $crudMenu->justSubMenu($infoMenu,194);


foreach ($infoMenu as $key => $value) {
    $info = $crudMenu->platosSubMenu($infoMenu,$infoMenu[$key][3]);
}

?>
<div class="container-fluid platos p-0 m-0">
    <div class="first">
        <?php foreach ($submenus as $key => $value) { ?>
        <div class="cabecal row flex-parent">
            <section class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                <div class="cabecalTitle flex-child">
                    <h2><?php echo $value ?></h2>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>


        <div class="row groupDish">
            <?php foreach ($info as $key => $value) { ?>
            <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 float-left">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h3 class="nameDish"><?php echo $value; ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <span><!-- <?php // echo $value[]; ?> --></span>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <div>
</div>
```

Que obtengo de cada array,

```
ARRAY INFOMENU
Array ( [0] => Array ( [nombre] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU 2 [0] => plato 1 [precio] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU 2 [id] => 194 [3] => 141 [4] => 194 ) [1] => Array ( [nombre] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU 2 [0] => plato 2 [precio] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU 2 [id] => 194 [3] => 141 [4] => 194 ) [2] => Array ( [nombre] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU [0] => plato aulacampius 2 [precio] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU [id] => 194 [3] => 140 [4] => 194 ) )
ARRAY INFO
Array ( [0] => plato aulacampius 2 )
ARRAY SUBMENUS
Array ( [0] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU 2 [2] => NOMBRE DEL SUBMENU )
```

Comment: Sergi, interesaría ver un ejemplo de lo que hay en los diferentes arrays, para revisar el código y quizá hasta para sugerirte un código optimizado. Puedes mostrar el contenido haciendo un `print_r($arrayMenu);`  y también `print_r($infoMenu);` y finalmente `print_r($submenus);` Y también convendría que pusieras un breve ejemplo del resultado que esperas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias, te he editado mi pregunta adjuntando los datos que me saca cada array. Un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($infoMenu as $key => $value) {
    $info = $crudMenu->platosSubMenu($infoMenu,$infoMenu[$key][3]);
}
```

Ahí tienes todo tu problema: estás sobreescribiendo el array contínuamente, no solo estás guardando nueva información. Una forma de arreglarlo sería:

```
  $info = [];
    foreach ($infoMenu as $key => $value) {
        $info[] = $crudMenu->platosSubMenu($infoMenu,$infoMenu[$key][3]);
    }
```

De esta forma creas un array con arrays, donde cada posición corresponde a un submenú, con las mismas posiciones que las que tienen los submenús en el array correspondiente, teniendo eso en cuenta, ya puedes mostrar los datos.

Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: Ahora solo me imprimime en los dos menus platos dos y plato aulacampius 2. No acabo de comprender el problema...